# How do I purchase a license for Gentoo?

Tags: linux, license, gentoo, licensing, software-activation

It looks like every genuine GNU/Linux distribution should have key servers and every user should purchase a license according to `https://gitlab.com/glat-official/howtotell`

I use Gentoo. I was unable to find where could I purchase a license and what key server URL should I use.

Where could I purchase retail license for Gentoo? Will I find key server URL in the box? If not, where is it?

Answer (score 7):

You are mistaken. Most Linux distros are totally free and are the assembly of software published under the [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) or other very permissive licenses.

So in the general case you don't need any kind of license to install Linux (and AFAIK Gentoo falls in that category).

Some distributions make you pay for maintenance/support (RedHat Enterprise Linux, for instance) but these are exceptions.

The link you refer is at best a hoax. You will note that it is a few days old and has a single anonymous author/maintainer. Given the already long Linux history, it should be older and have several maintainers.

Comment: What is GNU/Linux Activation Technologies then?

Comment: See edited answer. At best a hoax.

Comment: As mentioned, this appears to be a hoax or attempt to deceive into gathering licence fees by injecting malware into the distribution stream before it gets to end users. https://www.mail-archive.com/aur-requests@archlinux.org/msg33063.html looking at activity on the internet it only appeared only a week ago where it was injected to (and rejected from) the Arch Linux distro.